# New power supply, now computer doesn't recognise hard drive?

Tags: power-supply

Ok, I bought a new power supply, because my old one was too damn loud. I hooked it up to my PC, turned it on, everything is looking fine, start up detects my DVD drive, 2 hard disks.. then I get the message "BOOT FAILURE INSERT SYSTEM DISK".

Now I've seen some other people talk about going into BIOS and changing the start up to the HDD and not the CD.. well I've done that and it doesn't help.  If I let windows load up and it asks me to which partition I wish to install windows, no partition is present. It's as if after the initial start up the drives arn't being found.

I plugged my old (but loud) PSU back in, connected up all the cables, and it works perfectly.

Why does the new PSU not detect my HDD's after the first BIOS screen start up? Any ideas? :)

Comment: In the BIOS you should be able to show priority of which HDD to load first. If you can't find that, simply try to switch the SATA/IDE cable from the HDD with each other. Also, do you have more than 2 HDD or did the BIOS detect all your HDD's

Comment: Does the BIOS see the drive?

Answer (score 4):

The new one might underpower/not power your hard drive, try using a different cable to connect the power supply to the drive. If it still persists, try unplugging some peripherals (DVD drive, other disks, etc.) and see if it boots then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your hard-drive order in the BIOS. The first hard-drive should be the one which contains your operating system.